# Swift Animated Buttons jumping when first clicked

Tags: ios, swift, animation, button, cgaffinetransform

I've got some animations on some buttons, when they're touched down they shrink and grow back when released.

The issue I'm facing is that when the view is loaded and the buttons are first touched they kind of jump (as illustrated below). When clicked again their behavior is as expected.

[image]

Please note the spinning HOLD circles are not buttons but superimposed image views which confirms the buttons only have problems here. Also take into account that the transition to the `walletViewController` is not happening either and was deactivated as long as the issue is not fixed.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15) {
        self.badgeButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        self.holdAnimateBadge.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.15) {
        let imageView = self.holdAnimateBadge
        imageView?.alpha = 0.5
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonToWallet(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20) {
        self.badgeButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        self.badgeButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        self.holdAnimateBadge.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        self.holdAnimateBadge.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.20) {
        let imageView = self.holdAnimateBadge
        imageView?.alpha = 1
    }
    if badgeButton.image(for: UIControlState.normal) == UIImage(named: "SellImage") {
        let walletViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "walletViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(walletViewController!, animated: true)
    } else if badgeButton.image(for: UIControlState.normal) == UIImage(named: "BuyImage") {
        let walletViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "walletViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(walletViewController!, animated: true)
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be related to this `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)` animation and the fact that both actions are called at the same time but I don't why it happens only when first clicked and when the view is first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is the following: When you animate like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.20) {
    self.badgeButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    self.badgeButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
}
```

You change the transformation matrix twice, so the second assignment will overwrite the first. The first transformation therefore will be ignored.

Therefore I think you'll have to take a look at `animateKeyframesWithDuration` which allows you to add multiple animations (like zooming out and immediatly zooming back again).

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I tried using `animateKeyframesWithDuration` but can't achieve exactly the result I am after. Do you have any idea what the bug could be with my code? Today for instance the app works fine but yesterday it jumped like illustrated.. Also the bug is not present in the simulator..

Comment: First, why do you have two actions? Then, what are holdButton and holdAnimateBadge? Please remove all unnecessary code, ob provide a small, runnable Xcode project. Moreover, I wonder if the if statement works- I think comparing the images might not be a good idea.